# How to use association class?

Tags: oop

I am stuck with a problem while creating software design.

I have a list of students and each students can chose one or more subjects that they can study (Student and Subject class with name attribute) and also for each pair of Student and subject , some study partners (other students) has to be assigned .

For eg :

The list of students with name can be S1, S2, S3, S4.

The list of subjects with name can be SU1, SU2, SU3, SU4.

Now assign subjects to students

S1 --> SU1, SU3

S2 --> SU1, SU4

S3 --> SU2, SU3, SU4

S4 --> SU1, SU4

Now for each pair of student and subject we can have or cant have study partners

PS: any student other than himself.

S1, SU1 --> S2, S4

S1, SU3 --> S4

S2, SU1 --> NULL (no study partner)

S2, SU4 --> S3

S3, SU2 --> S1, S2

S3, SU3 --> NULL (no study partner)

S3, SU4 --> S4

S4, SU1 --> S1, S2

S4, SU4 --> S3

Appreciate help from anyone to design this model (UML diagram or sample code). I thought about association class but not sure how it fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps have a class that wraps around the concept of `Subject` and `StudyPartner`, like a `SubjectWrapper`, where

```
class SubjectWrapper
{
    Subject subject;

    List<Student> studyPartners
}
```

Instead of having a list of `Subject`, each student would have a list of `SubjectWrapper`, thus wrapping both the subject and the list of students that are study partners.

```
class Student
{
    // Name, Age, and what not...

    List<SubjectWrapper> subjects;
}
```

In this case an empty list would represent *no study partners*.