# View model , Model where to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is the continuation of the question mentioned in [How to use association class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143294/how-to-use-association-class) . Now the problem is

I have a wpf UI and i am using MVVM pattern to accomplish everything , where

1. in the first page i should be able to configure the Teachers (Add/remove/update). The attributes in the teacher class might be Name and Id.
2. In the second page i should be able to configure the Students and select a teacher for the student.
3. In the third page i should be able to configure the Subjects for the students.
4. In the fourth page i should be able to configure the Study partners for each student and his subject.

So if you see second page depends on the configuration done in the first page as the teachers information is based on the first page.

The third page depends on the second as only after creating a list of students in the second page then in the third page we assign the subjects.(Here the subject list is static no need to configure this.)

The fourth page depends on second and third page as the student info is configured (since the study partners are inturn students themselves) in second and the subject info for a student is configured in Third page.

My model defines and returns this Student , Teacher , Subject , StudyPartners info to the view model . Should all these classes (business objects) implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface ? Since i believe the UI specific things should be available only in viewmodel and not in model . If that is the case how the change notifications wii be taken care of, do we need to create a wrapper for all these classes in view model and have this property change notification implemented ? If we do this if the number of business objects increases wouldn't it become too much of wrappers in the view model ? How to tackle this issue? Did i make any mistake at design level or should all these things be taken care at UI level ?

Any help is appreciated , Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MVVM should the ViewModel or Model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always implemented it on the model.

- When working with a database back-end or file system back-end I mostly have another model on a lower level. So the model used on the views is just for displaying data.
- The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is not entirely restricted to user interfaces. You can do a lot of things with it. WPF simply uses it, but you can also use it on a lower level such as your database or file system.

A similar question as has been asked some time ago: [In MVVM should the ViewModel or Model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged) and as you can see there are also quite a lot of different opinions.

Comment: I can understand that the answer for this topic is very subjective . I thought may be for my situation there might be some concrete reasons saying where to implement the property notification exactly . Anyways thank you very much for the info.